# Dynamic values and legend entries in categorized layer symbology

Tags: qgis

I have a PostgreSQL table view that always shows me the 3 newest entries of a table based on the attribute "date". This view should be displayed as a layer with a categorized symbology. Is there a way to set the value and legend entry for the categorized values depending on the date attribute entries of the view?

[image]

Comment: Everything but the legend text can be made dynamic by adding an ordered row_number to the view definition or (if you cannot modify the view) via virtual layer - and building the categories from that (1,2,3). I know of no way to dynamically update the legend without python.